# How do I migrate CanPropertyChange("Text") from VB6 to VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

I want to upgrade an ActiveX control from VB6 to VB.NET. I'm having trouble upgrading this code:

```
If CanPropertyChange("Text") Then
    Text1.Text = Value
    RaiseEvent TextChange()
End If
```

I get the error: "**Name 'CanPropertyChange' is not declared.**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VB.Net does not support anything similar to the CanPropertyChange("Text") method.  The easiest way around this is to do the assignment within a Try...Catch block.

```
Try
  Text1.Text = Value
  RaiseEvent TextChange()
Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

If the property cannot be written to an exception will be thrown which you can access in the Catch block.